# NLTK Wordnet Download Out of Date

Tags: python-2.7, nltk, wordnet

New to Python, tying to get started with NLTK. After a rough time installing Python on my Windows 7 64-bit system, I am now having a rough time downloading Wordnet and other NLTK data packages located here:

http://nltk.org/nltk_data/

Some packages download, some say "Out of Date"

```
import nltk
nltk.download()
```

When I use the above to download, the program doesn't let me cancel if I hit the cancel button.

So, I just shut it down and go directly to the link above to try and download it manually.  When I try to download Wordnet for example, the download starts in my browser but stops mid-way through download!

This is very frustrating for me as a beginner.  Is there an alternative way to download Wordnet for nltk?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue. The issue in my case was that when the NLTK downloader started it had the server index as

http://nltk.github.com/nltk_data/

This needs to be changed to

http://nltk.org/nltk_data/

You can change this by going into the NLTK Downloader window and the File->Change Server Index.

Regards,
Bonson